# Sign Up button not redirecting to another page?

Tags: reactjs

Relatively new to working with React. Currently, I have a sidebar with a Sign Up button. When I click the SignUp button in the sidebar, the Sign Up form appears, but below the sidebar, instead of redirecting to a new page without the Sidebar.

I would like the Sign Up button to redirect to a new page. Where am I going wrong?

Full reproducible code is below.

Sidebar.js

```
import "../App.css";
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData'
import Logo from './Logo.svg'
import { LoginButton } from './LoginButton'
import { SignUpButton } from './SignUpButton'

function Sidebar() {
    return ( 
    <div className="Sidebar">
            <div className="Header">
        <div><img src = {Logo} alt='Logo'className='Logo' /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="line-break" />
           <ul className="SidebarList">
               {SidebarData.map((val, key) => {
                 return (
                  <li 
                    key={key} 
                    className="row"
                    id={window.location.pathname == val.link ? "active" : ""}
                    onClick={() => {
                        window.location.pathname = val.link;
                        }}
                    >
                      <div id="icon">{val.icon}</div> <div id="title">{val.title}</div>
                      </li>
               );
               })}
        
            </ul>
            <div class="line-break" />
<div className="footer">
            <ul className= "SidebarList">
                {LoginButton.map((val, key) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                        key={key}
                        className="Login"
                        id={window.location.pathname == val.link ? "active" : ""}
                        onClick={() => {
                            window.location.pathname = val.link;
                        }}
                        >
                            <div id="title">{val.title}</div>
                        </li>
                    )}
                
                )}
                
                 </ul>

                 <ul className= "SidebarList">
                {SignUpButton.map((val, key) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                        key={key}
                        className="SignUp"
                        id={window.location.pathname == val.link ? "active" : "/signup"}
                        onClick={() => {
                            window.location.pathname = val.link;
                        }}
                        >
                            <div id="title">{val.title}</div>
                        </li>
                    )}
                
                )}
                 </ul>
                 </div>
                 </div>



    )}; export default Sidebar;
```

Sign Up Page using Firebase

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword,  signOut } from 'firebase/auth'; //onAuthStateChanged is triggered everytime there is as change in state. If you reset the page, it will remember you.
import "../App.css";
import {auth} from "./firebase-config";

function SignUp () {

    const [registerEmail, setRegisterEmail] = useState("")
    const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState("")
    const [loginEmail, setLoginEmail] = useState("")
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("")
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser)
})

    const register = async () => {
        try {
        const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, registerEmail, registerPassword); //await because it will return a promise
        console.log(user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};

    

    const login = async () => {
        try {
            const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, loginEmail, loginPassword); //await because it will return a promise
            console.log(user)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };
        
    

    const logout = async () => {
        await signOut(auth);
    };

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Sign Up to the Platform</h1>
        <input placeholder="Email" onChange={(event) => {setRegisterEmail(event.target.value)}} /> 
        <input placeholder="Password" onChange={(event) => {setRegisterPassword(event.target.value)}} /> 
        <input placeholder="Business Name"/>
        <input placeholder="Your Role"/>
        <button onClick={register} >Sign Up</button>

        <h2> Login to the Platform</h2>
        <input placeholder="Email"onChange={(event) => {setLoginEmail(event.target.value)}} /> 
        <input placeholder="Password"onChange={(event) => {setLoginPassword(event.target.value)}} /> 
        <button onClick={login}>Log In</button>

<h4>User Logged In</h4> 
{user?.email} 
<button onClick={logout} > Sign Out</button>
    </div>

);
}



export default SignUp;
```

Sign Up Button component

```
export const SignUpButton = [
    {
        title: "Sign Up",
        link: "/signup",
    },
    
];
```

Router:

```
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import SignUp from "./Components/SignUpPage";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
    <Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
<Route Link to={SignUp} /> element={<SignUp/>} 
</Routes>
    </Router> //surround app with router, and conditionally display pages based on what the user is on
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: @KeatonBenning Yup, just added that code now to question. Thanks

Comment: use  a `<Link to={val.link} />`

Comment: `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: @KeatonBenning Can you submit an answer showing this?

Comment: @KeatonBenning updated code

Answer (score 1):

In react-router-dom you can use multiple ways to change pages. One way is to use `<Link to={val.link} />` another way is to use `history.push();`

you can import it by `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`

You will also eventually want to look into using history in your browserRouter. That way you can hit the back button. `history.push(-1);`

ALSO its worth it to note Version 6 is out and the function names have changed https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6

Comment: How does this stop it from showing on a page with my sidebar however? Does not seem to be working for me

Comment: im confused by your question. What isnt working?